How Does Shri Madhvacharya interpret the following
Consider the following translation from the Bhagavat Purana:

आत्मनश्च परस्यापि यः करोत्यन्तरोदरम् । तस्य भिन्नदृशो मृत्युः विदधे भयमुल्बणम् ॥ २६ ॥


If a person makes even a slight difference between himself and the Supreme Self (Paramātman), I, who am Death, create a big fear for him who entertains the idea of difference.

~ Bhagavatam 3.29.26
This seems to strongly suggest Advaita not Dvaita. How does Shri Madhvacharya and the Dwaita vaadis interpret this verse?

Here is an interpretation, presumably based on Gaudiya Vaishnava sampradaya -   https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/3/29/26/

@estimator Thank you very much for pointing out how the verse has Advaitic and Dvaitic interpretations
